# capital X sans-serif symbol for optic magnification

Tags: text, magnification

Ok, maybe this is easy but i cannot figure it out: i came accross the need to write in an elsevier article a number of microscope magnification (like 20X). Now the direct easy way is of course `20$\times$` but to be super-picky i don't like too much the math ex that doesn't fit with the text font, not to mention the horrible "20X" which will print a capital X with serif.

Is there any dedicated "big enough" capital X sans serif for inline text-style magnification symbol for optics (maybe a ding) or we just have to force a sans-serif capital X and that's all (which would be sad for a LaTeX enthusiast)?

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: do you want an X at all rather than `$20\times$` ? If you want it to look like the X fron the sans serif font then `20\textsf{X}` but a `\times` seems semantically clearer (not that semantics is evrything in typography:-)

Comment: The problem is that by simply using an X you will get a serif font in elsevier journal. On the other side there is no such symbol i found which will give you a \times-like but high enough to match the text "20"...

Comment: Ok i went through the complete list of symbols and i think there is no such a "special dedicated" symbol for magnification. It looks like it's a simple capital X with no serif. Do you agree? i am searching for some old textbook to report my desired outcome...

Comment: I don't know how Elsevier publish their journals, but chances are they don't actually typeset the articles with LaTeX. In that case a complicated solution that involves font hacking in whatever shape or form may not actually give the expected results when things are published. I'm inclined to claim that it is the journal editor's job to make sure that the "20X" looks nice, but I am aware of the possibility that that might slip through the cracks or that the editor thinks differently or that an editor has been replaced by a robot to maximise revenue.

Comment: The Wiki page for "[Magnification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification)" uses the "multiplication sign": [`U+00D7`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm), which is similar to `$\times$`.

Comment: You might want to use `\ding{53}` from `pifont` or `\XSolid` from `bbding`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four possibilities (the first is best, in my opinion).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}

%% needs no package
\newcommand{\perA}{\textsf{X}}
%% needs graphicx
\newcommand{\perB}{%
  \resizebox{!}{1.2\fontcharht\font`0}{$\mkern-2mu\times\mkern-2mu$}% 
}
%% needs pifont
\newcommand{\perC}{\ding{53}}

\begin{document}

20$\times$

20\perA

20\perB

20\perC

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the first and the third one are the closer to what i saw in old books. So the $\times$ solution at the end looks one of the best chioces. I'm gonna use them thank you!